# Ошибка при вызове поля объекта

Tags: php, json

```
$rain='<p>обсяг дощу за останні 3 години: '.$lists->rain->3h.'</p>';
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '3' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pog.php on line 16

Я так понял что ругается на название поля `->3h`, но поменять название немогу потому что использую API чужого сайта

Comment: Ошибка говорит о неожиданном числе, когда ожидает строку или переменную

Comment: [`$lists->rain["3h"]`](http://php.net/manual/ru/sdo.sample.getset.php#example-5939)

Comment: Такая ошибка: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К полям, имеющим недопустимое с точки зрения парсера PHP имя, можно обращаться через вот такой синтаксис:

```
$rain='<p>обсяг дощу за останні 3 години: '.$lists->rain->{"3h"}.'</p>';
```

Comment: использовал такой синтаксис выдает другую ошибку Undefined property: stdClass::$3h in C:\xampp\htdocs\pog.php on line 16

Comment: Все получилось нада еще ставить проверку сначала isset $lists->rain->{"3h"}